# Spring Securty - How to share bcrypt between two applications?

Tags: spring, hash, spring-security, credentials, bcrypt

I have a REST api application where the credentials are stored as hashes in a database table. Additionally I have another application which administrates the credentials for the first application. I generated in both application an DelagtingPasswordEncoder.

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder delegatingPasswordEncoder() {
    PasswordEncoder defaultEncoder = NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    Map<String, PasswordEncoder> encoders = new HashMap<>();
    encoders.put("bcrypt", new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    encoders.put("scrypt", new SCryptPasswordEncoder());

    DelegatingPasswordEncoder passworEncoder = new DelegatingPasswordEncoder("bcrypt", encoders);
    passworEncoder.setDefaultPasswordEncoderForMatches(defaultEncoder);

    return passworEncoder;
}
```

When I try to authenicate at the REST api with a credential generated by the administration application I get an Unauthorized 401. The bcrypt hash generated in the administrator application could not be matched by the bcrypt of the REST api application. I assume the random salt generated by bcrypt is also dependent on the context it is initialized in?

We used Basic Auth for the test, with the correct password generated by the administration appliction before storing it as a hash in the database.

Both applications share the same database, but are otherwise independent from each other.

Is it possible to use bcrypt in both applications or what is the best way to exchange the passwords between both applications?

Comment: My implementation was wrong. Now I just create an independent BcryptPasswordEncoder and save the password in the ADMIN application and the API application can match it. So everything works as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to share the BCrypt encoder between applications.

The structure of the `BCryptPasswordEncoder` hash is a concatenation of:

- hashing algorithm
- number of hash iterations
- salt
- hashed salt + password

When you do an authentication, you basically get a username and a password from the user request, fetch the user based on the provided username from the database, extract the hashing algorithm, number of iterations and salt from the hashed password from the database, hash the request password based on that data and then compare the hashes. There is no salt generation involved when you authenticate a user. Salt is generated only when you create or update a password.

Note that the hashing algorithm, number of iterations and salt extraction is done behind the hood by the `matches` method from `BCryptPasswordEncoder` (which takes as arguments the hashed password and the plain password).

My best guess is that you are not using the `matches` method from `BCryptPasswordEncoder` to compare the request password with the DB password, but rehash the request password and compare the resulted hash with the db hash. This won't work, since the encoded method will generate a new salt with which will hash the password, resulting in different hashes.

Comment: I have a handling for clear text passwords to be hashed on first authentication. I have this for migration purposes. We put the clear text passwords into the database and on the first authentication request they get hashed and the hashed value is stored. Then only the hashed value is validated by using the matches  method. This works fine in the REST application. Only for hashes generated by the administration application it does not work. In both applications I generate a DelegatingPasswordEncoder Bean which are autowired in the services to generate the hash via encode.

Comment: So it does not matter that there are different beans in different applications? The bcrypt hash should be validated through the matches method in any case?

Comment: Yes, BCrypt is a deterministic algorithm. Given the same input it will always generate the same output.